# How to overlay a UIButton (close) button on top of a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have been looking and trying to solve an issue I have with a UIWebView for iOS.

I have a very small app which just loads my website the source code lives at https://github.com/pjuu/iotter.

On the site when a user clicks on a posted image it load the image URL in to the web view. This leaves them stranded and unable to get back to other parts of the site.

What I want to do is display an (x) button in the top right hand corner (no matter what screen rotation is in use) and have perform the back operation in the browser.

I know this question isn't a code issue as I'm fine to sort of the Swift code part of it. I just could not for the life of me work out how to add the button programmatically and have it display over the webview.

The only tutorials I could find involved creating a tool bar to perform these type of actions which I think would take up to much space when looking at an image.

The question is very simple:

- Is this possible?
- If so how would I go about creating the button?

I am going to check the `request.path` parameter with regex to only show it if it matches an image URL.

Apologies if this isn't fitting enough for SO. I am happy to move the question or post on another site.

Thank you for any help in advance. I am not a mobile developer so using XCode and the storyboard stuff is a world away from vim for me.

Comment: `UIWebView` is an `UIView` it can then manage subviews, `UIButton` is an `UIView` you can then add an `UIButton` on your `UIWebView` and manage it as usual. I think you must move to XCode env, life will be easier...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I am using XCode that is where a lot of the confusion is coming from. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**REFERENCE:**

1) CGRectMake: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake

2) UIWebViewDelegate:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

---

**SOLUTION:**

**1) Create the "X" UIButton:**

```
// Define the UIButton

let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
let image = UIImage(named: "name") as UIImage?
button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width - 60, 30, 35, 35)
button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(button)

//Hide the UIButton

button.hidden = true
```

**2) Detect when an imageUrl is opened and make the "X" UIButton appear:**

```
// This function is triggered every time a request is made:

optional func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    let string = request.URL

    if string.rangeOfString(".png") || string.rangeOfString(".jpg")|| string.rangeOfString(".jpeg"){
        // code to make cross appear
        // for example:
        self.button.hidden = false
    }
}
```

**3) Finally, you will need to create the method that closes the page when the "X" UIButton is tapped:**

```
func btnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    if(webview.canGoBack) {
        //Go back in webview history
        webview.goBack()
    } else {
        //Pop view controller to preview view controller
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

---

**N.B.:**

In the lines:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "cross.png") as UIImage?
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

We are setting the UIButton to be the image of a cross.
You need to add a cross image to your XCode project and set the "cross.png" String to the exact name of your image: "nameOfImage.fileType".

Comment: Thanks for the answer the developer link is really useful. I will take a look for just creating the UIButton and setting the constraints. At least I know this is possible.

Comment: @JoeDoherty You are welcome :D I am editing my answer with some code snippets so you can see how to add constraints programmatically ;)

Comment: WOW! Thank you sooo much. I was on the correct lines trying this last night but would never have got this. This looks like it will work. I will accept your answer when I get home and can test this if that is okay. Think this may be useful for the future :)

Comment: @JoeDoherty :D Happy I could help ! This will make the cross appear in the middle though. I don't know if that's what you want. I thinj top right corner would be more usual.

Comment: Yea top right is what I'm going to do. I can have a fiddle though with the constraints. Will probably be a good learning exercise :)

Comment: @JoeDoherty Do you know how to use add an image to your XCODE project ?

Comment: Sort of. I have a XIB thing in there and the icons. Is it similar?

Comment: @JoeDoherty Not sure. Let me add a gif.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much. This is a lot of work and probably one of the best answers to any question I have seen.

Comment: @JoeDoherty Happy to help :D I would have felt bad leaving you with a half answer where you would have had to search for the other half on google :) After all, SO is made to find solutions to dev problems ! It would make no sense to create a solution that addresses only half the question !

Answer (score 0):

Simple one line solution.

Create a desired "close" button in storyboard, or programmatically.

Then, just send your WebView to the back of all current views displayed in your view controller:

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(yourWebView)
```

Now, all views (including any buttons you create) will be displayed on top if it. Just be sure to add this line after all of your desired views are created.