# Overlay a refresh button over a UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uibutton

I am attempting to add a button in the top right corner of my app that will reload my `webView`. I have attempted to follow other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204402/how-to-overlay-a-uibutton-close-button-on-top-of-a-uiwebview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31708014/overlay-an-uibutton-over-an-uiwebview-in-swift), but have not had any luck getting the button to show up.

I have the following code in my ViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView.multipleTouchEnabled = true
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")!))
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```

I would like to overlay the button. How could I add a button to reload the `webView` when pressed?

Comment: there is no code related to adding the button, can you show it please so we can help

Comment: As @MejdiLassidi pointed out, the code for adding the button is missing. If you are using xib/storyboard and have the button there, please keep in mind that the `AddSubview` will put the `webView` at the top; thus hiding the button made in the xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add button to your web view hierarchy e.g.

```
    let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)
    let button = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    webView.scrollView.addSubview(button) // in that way button will be scroling with webView.
```

or add button above webView e.g.

```
        let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)
        let button = UIButton(frame: buttonFrame)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: webView)
```

Comment: The second one is exactly what I needed. I changed the last line to `webView.insertSubview(button, aboveSubview: webView)`

Comment: I'm happy that I could help you :)